# Django, Nextjs | set-cookie is not set in the browser even though the value is set

Tags: django, next.js

I am creating a JWT authentication with Django and Nextjs.
I can implement the signup and login functionality, I can get the accessToken by logging in.

However, the response header is Set-Cookie is set in the browser(chrome, safari,firefox) even though there is a cookie.

What are the possible causes?

https://github.com/Git-Port/django-next

##### response header

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://localhost:3000
Allow: POST, OPTIONS
Content-Length: 715
Content-Type: application/json
Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin
Date: Tue, 11 Jan 2022 04:34:59 GMT
Referrer-Policy: same-origin
Server: Werkzeug/2.0.2 Python/3.9.7
Set-Cookie: jwt-auth=〇〇; expires=Tue, 11 Jan 2022 05:34:59 GMT; HttpOnly; Max-Age=3600; Path=/; SameSite=None; Secure
Set-Cookie: csrftoken=〇〇; expires=Tue, 10 Jan 2023 04:34:59 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/; SameSite=None; Secure
Set-Cookie: sessionid=〇〇; expires=Tue, 25 Jan 2022 04:34:59 GMT; HttpOnly; Max-Age=1209600; Path=/; SameSite=None; Secure
Vary: Accept, Cookie, Origin
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
```

##### Environment

```
Django==4.0.1
Nextjs
```

Server Domain
`https://127.0.0.1:8000`

Front Domain
`‌https://localhost:3000`

##### settings.py | Django

```py
CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = False
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    'http://127.0.0.1:3000',
    'http://localhost:3000',
    'https://127.0.0.1:3000',
    'https://localhost:3000',
]
```

##### index.js | Next

```js
const login = async (data) => {
    const res = await axios.post("https://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/login/", data, {withCredentials: true})
  };
```

Comment: you ever get this worked out - im stuck now too

Answer (score 0):

I looked into your code and I think the problem is with different domains. Cookies with httponly can only be send on samesite domain. So in your example you have frontend/next on "localhost" and backend/server on "127.0.0.1". If you change both to "localhost" or both to "127.0.0.1" it should work.

Also note on production that this is also the case, so you would need to serve API from same domain as next app.